# Tkinter GUI not in proper place

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to create a Tkinter GUI a grey box with a label at the top, then below that a drop down box and with a label to its left describing it and below that another drop down box with a label to its left. Instead I am getting the label in the proper place but then the two drop down boxes and labels are on top of each other even though they are in different frames.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk


class review_gui():


    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()

        self.EDM_GUI(1)

        self.root.mainloop()


    def EDM_GUI(self, column):
        self.EDM_frm = Frame(self.root, background = "grey")
        self.EDM_frm.pack(side = "top")

        EDM_Label_frm = Frame(self.EDM_frm).pack(side = "top")
        EDM_DD_frm = Frame(self.EDM_frm).pack(side = "bottom")

        EDM_DB_frm = Frame(EDM_DD_frm).pack(side = "top")
        EDM_Port_frm = Frame(EDM_DD_frm).pack(side = "bottom")



        EDM_lbl = Label(EDM_Label_frm, text="EDM", fg="black").pack()

        EDM_DD_label = Label(EDM_DB_frm, text="Select EDM:", fg="black")
        EDM_DD_label.pack(side="left")
        EDM_Drop_Down = ttk.Combobox(EDM_DB_frm, state="readonly")
        EDM_Drop_Down["values"] = ("One", "Two", "Three")
        EDM_Drop_Down.pack(side="right")



        EDM_P_label = Label(EDM_Port_frm, text="Select Portfolio:", fg="black")
        EDM_P_label.pack(side="left")
        Port_Drop_Down = ttk.Combobox(EDM_Port_frm, state="readonly")
        Port_Drop_Down["values"] = ("One", "Two", "Three")
        Port_Drop_Down.pack(side="right")

rg = review_gui()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standart `pack` geometry manager may seem bizarre and wayward, but it's not true. One thing that you must understand is the sequence of your actions!

So main alghorithm is this:

1. An instance (of a widget or a container) is created, and associated with its parent.
2. The instance is packed.

In other words: imagine that you are building a house! In your example, you start building a house right in the hardware store or wherever, so your house is not built according to your plans.

Try to imagine that each frame is the floor of the house. And the widgets inside it are furniture! So first you plan your floors with furniture and then pack it in order you wish.

I modified little bit your `EDM_GUI` function and it looks like it's working like you desired! Just remember to avoid declaration and packing in one line,  because `pack` returns `None`.

**Example**:

```
def EDM_GUI(self, column):
    self.EDM_frm = Frame(self.root, background="grey")
    self.EDM_frm.pack()

    EDM_Label_frm = Frame(self.EDM_frm).pack()
    EDM_DD_frm = Frame(self.EDM_frm).pack()

    EDM_DB_frm = Frame(EDM_DD_frm)
    EDM_Port_frm = Frame(EDM_DD_frm)



    EDM_lbl = Label(EDM_Label_frm, text="EDM", fg="black").pack()

    EDM_DD_label = Label(EDM_DB_frm, text="Select EDM:", fg="black")
    EDM_DD_label.pack(side="left")
    EDM_Drop_Down = ttk.Combobox(EDM_DB_frm, state="readonly")
    EDM_Drop_Down["values"] = ("One", "Two", "Three")
    EDM_Drop_Down.pack(side="right")
    EDM_DB_frm.pack(side="top")



    EDM_P_label = Label(EDM_Port_frm, text="Select Portfolio:", fg="black")
    EDM_P_label.pack(side="left")
    Port_Drop_Down = ttk.Combobox(EDM_Port_frm, state="readonly")
    Port_Drop_Down["values"] = ("One", "Two", "Three")
    Port_Drop_Down.pack(side="right")
    EDM_Port_frm.pack(side="bottom")
```

**Result**:

[image: output]

**Addition**:
To your question about preserving and logic of `pack` manager:
I don't exactly know how `pack` manager works under the hood, but you can test, if something going wrong or not by adding borders to your frames!
Just declare your frames like that: `FrameVar = Frame(parent, relief='raised', borderwidth=10)`. As you see - outframed widgets placed directly to your `root` window!

So I tested 3 variants (from your question, from my answer and correct one):

1. Totally outframed one (from your question)

[image: totallyoutframed]

2. Partially outframed one (from my answer)

[image: partiallyoutframed]

3. Correct one, all items in frames

[image: correctone]

**Correct code**:

```
def EDM_GUI(self, column):
    self.EDM_frm = Frame(self.root)

    EDM_Label_frm = Frame(self.EDM_frm)
    EDM_lbl = Label(EDM_Label_frm, text="EDM", fg="black").pack()
    EDM_Label_frm.pack()

    EDM_DD_frm = Frame(self.EDM_frm)

    EDM_DB_frm = Frame(EDM_DD_frm)
    EDM_DD_label = Label(EDM_DB_frm, text="Select EDM:", fg="black")
    EDM_DD_label.pack(side="left")
    EDM_Drop_Down = ttk.Combobox(EDM_DB_frm, state="readonly")
    EDM_Drop_Down["values"] = ("One", "Two", "Three")
    EDM_Drop_Down.pack(side="right")
    EDM_DB_frm.pack(side="top")

    EDM_Port_frm = Frame(EDM_DD_frm)
    EDM_P_label = Label(EDM_Port_frm, text="Select Portfolio:", fg="black")
    EDM_P_label.pack(side="left")
    Port_Drop_Down = ttk.Combobox(EDM_Port_frm, state="readonly")
    Port_Drop_Down["values"] = ("One", "Two", "Three")
    Port_Drop_Down.pack(side="right")
    EDM_Port_frm.pack(side="bottom")

    EDM_DD_frm.pack()
    self.EDM_frm.pack()
```

*P.S. Use a wildcard import only if you love global namespace pollution.*

Comment: Thanks CommonSense, so I was packing the frames before I put widgets in them when you have to put the widgets in them before they are packed. One question though how come when I created EDM_Label_frm and EDM_DD_frm it preserves the packing order and puts the EDM_Label_frm before EDM_DD_frm. But when I create the two frames EDM_DB_frm and EDM_Port_frm it combines them and does not keep the packing order?

Comment: @Christopher Ell, I updated my answer, to show how wrong you about preserving.

Comment: re _" I don't exactly know how pack manager works under the hood"_ - the canonical description is here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/pack.htm#M26

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, I know about "childrens of the root" as I mentioned in addition. So, after all, on last example isn't all working as expected? And thanks for link!

Comment: yes, your second solution is working as expected. I had based my comment on the first code, but I failed to see that you provided a second solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The problem stems from you calling `pack` at the same time that you create a widget:

```
EDM_Label_frm = Frame(self.EDM_frm).pack(side = "top")
```

In python, when you do `foo().bar()`, the result is whatever `bar()` returns. Thus, in the case of `Frame(...).pack(...)`, you get what `.pack(...)` returns. `pack` always returns `None`, so `EDM_Label_frm` is set to `None`.

Because `EDM_Label_frm` is set to `None`, any children of this frame actually end up as children of the root frame. When you call `pack` or `grid`, you end up placing them inside the root window.

For this reason, you should separate widget creation from widget layout. I suggest you always do this, though technically you only need to do this when you need to use the widget as arguments to other commands.

If you make that one change, the UI will look a lot closer to what you expect. I find it best to always group layout within a parent together so it's easier to get an overall view of the layout. In many cases I think it makes for more readable code when you group *all* layout together.

For example:

```
EDM_Label_frm = Frame(self.EDM_frm)
EDM_DD_frm = Frame(self.EDM_frm)
EDM_DB_frm = Frame(EDM_DD_frm)
EDM_Port_frm = Frame(EDM_DD_frm)

self.EDM_frm.pack(side = "top")
EDM_Label_frm.pack(side = "top")
EDM_DD_frm.pack(side = "bottom")
EDM_DB_frm.pack(side = "top")
EDM_Port_frm.pack(side = "bottom")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help