# Changing entry text in tkinter, if the entry is created from list

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I created 12 Entry boxes using a for loop with a default value of `N/A`. Any change in the text of entry is detected through `.trace` method.

I want to use reset button to make all the text on the Entry Boxes back to `N/A`

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


t_diesel_price_EnF_variable = ["JanVar", "FebVar", "MarVar", "AprVar","MayVar","JuneVar","JulyVar","AugVar","SeptVar", "OctVar", "NovVar", "DecVar"]
t_diesel_price_EnF_values = ["N/A", "N/A","N/A", "N/A","N/A", "N/A","N/A", "N/A","N/A", "N/A","N/A", "N/A"]

def EnFChanging(*events):
    for EnF in range(0,len(t_diesel_price_EnF_variable)):
        t_diesel_price_EnF_values[EnF]=t_diesel_price_EnF_variable[EnF].get()
        try:
            t_diesel_price_EnF_values[EnF] = float(t_diesel_price_EnF_values[EnF])
        except ValueError:
            pass
    print(t_diesel_price_EnF_values)


for EnF in range(0,len(t_diesel_price_EnF_values)):
    t_diesel_price_EnF_variable[EnF] = StringVar(root , value = "N/A")
    t_diesel_price = Entry(root , textvariable =  t_diesel_price_EnF_variable[EnF], width = 10).pack()
    t_diesel_price_EnF_variable[EnF].trace("w",EnFChanging)


def ChangeText():
    for EnF in range(0, len(t_diesel_price_EnF_values)):
        t_diesel_price[EnF].delete(0,END)
        t_diesel_price[EnF].insert(0,"N/A")

    return

b1 = Button(root, text = "Reset" , command = ChangeText).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

When I press the button it gives an error `t_diesel_price[EnF].delete(0,END)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

What should I do now, Please ignore the basic errors of programming as I am a Mechanical Engineer with not a programming back ground. And I have to make a lot of other boxes too for my energy calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying treat `t_diesel_price` as an `Entry` (and as a `list`) when your variable is `None`.
First of all I suggest you to install some IDE (e.g. PyCharm) and place break points to see whats wrong with variable!

Your problem occures because you create and pack your widget in one line! So `t_diesel_price` is `None` because `pack()` always returns `None` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42813145/6634373)).
Just split your declaration and packing to:

```
t_diesel_price = Entry(root , textvariable =  t_diesel_price_EnF_variable[EnF], width = 10)
t_diesel_price.pack()
```

After that it's works for me, except this fact that `t_diesel_price` is last created entry and the value changes only in it. So I assume that you need another list to iterate over entries:

```
...
# another fresh list
t_diesel_price_EnF_entries = list()    
...
    # declare entry
    t_diesel_price = Entry(root, textvariable=t_diesel_price_EnF_variable[EnF], width=10) 
    # pack entry    
    t_diesel_price.pack()                                                                       
    # append entry to list
    t_diesel_price_EnF_entries.append(t_diesel_price)                                           
...
def ChangeText():
    # iterate over entries
    for diesel_price in t_diesel_price_EnF_entries:
        diesel_price.delete(0,END)
        diesel_price.insert(0,"N/A")
...
```

Alternatively you can iterate over `StringVar`'s if you don't wanna store your entries at all:

```
def ChangeText():
    # iterate over stringvars
    for EnF in range(len(t_diesel_price_EnF_variable)):
        t_diesel_price_EnF_variable[EnF].set('N/A')
```

And you can make it more readable as in example with entry iterating:

```
def ChangeText():
    # iterate over stringvars
    for string_var in t_diesel_price_EnF_variable:
        string_var.set('N/A')
```

Cheers!